# How to clear all cached images loaded from SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, sdwebimage

I have all images loaded on my app via SDWebImage. The downloading and caching works great, but I wanted to make a button that can clear all cached images in the entire app.

I have a "Clear Cache" button as a UIButton on one of my tab bar views. How can I make it so when this button is tapped, all the cached images are removed and need to be re-downloaded?

Using Swift.

Thank you!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to completely clear the cache do the following:

#### Obj-c:

```
- (IBAction)clearCache:(id)sender {
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]clearMemory];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]clearDisk];
}
```

#### Swift 5

```
SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()
```

#### Swift 3.0

```
@IBAction func clearCache(sender: UIButton) {
    SDImageCache.shared().clearMemory()
    SDImageCache.shared().clearDisk()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I link this up to a UIButton? Would it be through an outlet?

Comment: Will try this. Thank you!

Comment: Is SDWebimage library manage automatic remove images from the cached? If we are not using any more since 2 to 3 days and more.

Comment: FYI, clearDisk has been changed to clearDiskOnCompletion:.

Comment: @tounaobun the declaration is `func clearDisk(onCompletion completion: SDWebImageNoParamsBlock? = nil)`, so the `onCompletion` parameter can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func actClearCache(sender:AnyObject) {

   let objCache = SDImageCache.sharedImageCache()
   objCache.clearMemory()
   objCache.cleanDisk()

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I link this up to a UIButton? Would it be through an outlet?

Comment: Got it, thanks! I am getting an error that says: Use of unresolved identifier 'SDImageCache'. Would I need to import it in my bridging header?

Comment: Have you ‘import SDWebImage`? And which swift version are you using?

Comment: Here's my bridging header: #import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SDWebImane" 

It says that 'SdWebImane' file not found

Comment: I imported SDWebImage, and I think I'm using Swift 2.2

Comment: I didn't write "import SDWebImage" on the .swift file attached to the View controller. It works now that I've wrote it!

Comment: As of this date cleanDisk and clearDisk are missing from SDImageCache.h.  But they're still in http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.3/Classes/SDImageCache.html#//api/name/clearDisk

Answer (score 2):

To delete all data from cache

```
SDImageCache.shared.clear(with: .all) {
    print("Disk & memory data cleared")
}
```

To delete data from only memory

```
SDImageCache.shared.clear(with: .memory) {
    print("Memory data cleared")
}
```

To delete data from disk

```
SDImageCache.shared.clear(with: .disk) {
    print("Disk data cleared")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 , Xcode 10**

> pod 'SDWebImage', '5.0.0-beta3'

```
import SDWebImage

 @IBAction func ClearCacheButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
     SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
     SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5

```
import SDWebImage

  SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()

  SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()
```