# SDWebImage is loading partially and is not loading back even after killing the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sdwebimage

Images are partially loaded and even though I have killed the and started back. Also this comes up rarely hence unable to reach out the exact issue. The image is not correcting itself and remains as such due to caching. But need a solution to fix this.
A reference of code and image is attached.

```
extension UIImageView {

    public func sd_setImageWithURLWithFade(url: URL!, placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage? = nil) {

        self.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholder, options: SDWebImageOptions.allowInvalidSSLCertificates)
        { (image, error, imageCacheType, imageUrl) in

            if let downLoadedImage = image {
                if imageCacheType == .none {
                    self.image = downLoadedImage
                }
            } else {
                self.image = placeholder
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's happen in first time or every time?
may be your image size is large..

Comment: It happens sometimes, very rare issue but do persits

Comment: Check the image size and try to reduce to speed up download times, which may prevent storing of half downloaded images altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, SDImage framework is storing the cached image for a particular image. So, now if due to some poor internet connection, if image gets downloaded partially and later you try to load the image from the same url, it will check for the existing image in cache and show you that image instead of the new image.

Thus, you are seeing the partially downloaded image even after you are re-running the app. If you delete that app and try running it again, and there will be no network issues, then it will download the full image and then onwards it will show you the fully downloaded image.

> So, can say: that's the limitations to SDImageView.

Comment: Hi, I do understand that issue is coming due to caching but what would be a viable fix to it

Comment: You can try this as option SDWebImageRefreshCached, it will check and try to download the image again, if something wrong occurred while last download or if image changed at the same URL. Use this option, if not affecting the performance.

Comment: The problem is the issue comes very rarely and am also not able to trace it back. So how should I check whether its fixed or not. Is there someway to track or reproduce this issue?

Comment: yes, you can clear cache and memory in viewDidLoad method, while testing this. code to clear it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881566/how-to-clear-all-cached-images-loaded-from-sdwebimage

Comment: and once the image start downloading, you can put iPhone to AirPlane mode to stop internet. Also, use the mobile data by setting network speed to 2G in your iphone settings.

Comment: @Ishika Have you tried the suggestions and fixed your issues?

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce back the issue